# Запись строки в базу данных используя jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

не судите строго с базами не работал. У меня есть метод который читает из файла данные мне необходимо их записать в базу я создал конекшен к базе через jdbc, как мне передать данные в метод который конекшен ? Или ткните носом где почитать. Спасибо примеру буду очень рад.

```
@Override
public void save(String message) {
   try(Connection c = getConnection()){

            String sql =  "INSERT INTO sms_log  () VALUES (? ,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1,1);
        ps.setInt(1,79);
        ps.setString(1,"Hello");
        ps.setDate(1,new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

        ps.execute();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Драйвер подключен");
    System.out.println("Соединение установлено");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms_server","root", "530433");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем проблема, вы передаёте какое-то сообщение в метод save(String message).

Если в сообщение содержаться все данные, необходимые для запроса и разделены каким-то символом используется .split()

```
@Override
public void save(String message) {
   try(Connection c = getConnection()){

        String sql =  "INSERT INTO sms_log  () VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        //Если значения разделены запятой
        List<String> mes = Arrays.asList(message.split(","));

        ps.setInt(1, mes[0]);
        ps.setInt(1,mes[1]);
        ps.setString(1,mes[2]);
        ps.setDate(1,new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

        ps.execute();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```